# how do I override a static variable of a class

Tags: java, box2d

I'm using a library it has a public static float variable I want to know how to override it
I guess that's not going to happen?

```
//Settings.java
package org.jbox2d.common;

public class Settings {
    public static float velocityThreashold = 1.0f;
}

//MyClass.class
package org.jbox2d.common;

import com.otherlibrary
public class MyClass {

}
```

Thanks

Comment: I am confused with your example code as it is declared `static` but not `final`. Why not just change the value?

Comment: Rob modify your question, please. What is final, what is static

Comment: sorry my questions sucks. as im sure you can tell im not really a java programmer. its not final at all. its my eyes playing tricks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The velocityThreashold variable in your example is not final, nor is it an instance variable and therefore cannot technically be overridden.

What you can do is set the value of velocityThreashold to any value you want since it's public.

I think what you're going to want to do is something like the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  org.jbox2d.common.Settings.velocityThreashold = 2.0f;

  //... the rest of your program
}
```

Comment: indeed my question was rubbish its nothing to do with final. this is what I need :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can not override member variables in Java. You can use something called field hiding instead. Have a look at [this](http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2008/06/field-hiding-in-java-fields-are-only.html).

However in your example `velocityThreashold` isn't final so you can change it's value.

Answer (score 0):

Override variable? If you mean method then:

You can't override static method because static elements isn't inherited

Answer (score 0):

You can't, that's the point of them being final.

As for you code you don't have a final variable so you just have to change the value and that's it.