# How are variables overridden

Tags: java, variables, static, overriding

```
package com.mycompany.myproject.mypkg;

interface MyInterface {
    public static final int k = 9;
}

class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    // int k = 89;
}

public class SampleThree extends MyClass {
    static int k = 90;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyClass object = new SampleThree();
        System.out.println(object.k);
    }
}
```

Why does the above program print '9' instead of '90'?

How are static and member variables overridden in Java?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I override a static variable of a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397082/how-do-i-override-a-static-variable-of-a-class)

Comment: I didn't even realize it was possible to declare static fields as part of an interface.

Comment: local variables (which you don't have any) and member fields are not overridden, they are only hidden using Scoping rules.

Answer (score 5):

Because fields do not support polymorphism. `MyClass.k` is `9` (and `object` is of refered to by `MyClass`). `SampleThree.k` would give you `90`. Each class has its own set of variables.

(Btw, An IDE would give you a warning here that you are accessing a static variable by an instance, rather than by its class.)

Answer (score 1):

Because inheritance is intended to modify behaviour. Behaviour is exposed through methods and those methods can be overridden .

What you can do is to overload a field , not override . 
For that you need to define that variable outside the Interface in order to give them different values .

Answer (score 0):

You have a static variable `k` in interface `MyInterface`. You have implement this interface in class `MyClass`, then `MyClass.k` should be 9.

Object is refered to by `MyClass`. `SampleThree.k` would give you 90.

Or simply:

> Static variable can not be override.

Rules for Overriding static and instance variable & methods:

1. A compilation error occurs if an instance method overrides a static method.
2. A compilation error occurs if a static method hides an instance method.
3. It's permissible for a static variable to hide an instance variable.
4. It's also permissible for an instance variable to hide a static variable.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding concept is not applicable to variables(hence overriding rules). The value is always based on reference type but not based on the run time object.

That's why your program is printing 9 because the reference type of object is `MyClass`, and `MyClass` inherited k whose value is 9.The behavior is same irrespective of the **static** modifier(k ).If you uncomment the line in `MyClass` the output is always 89.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating Reference Variable of MyClass. So if using this variable you will access k then it will show variable of interface. If you want to access variable having value 90 make reference variable of SampleThree class.