# why we can't override the variables in java

Tags: java

why we can't override the variables in java , It hides variable

```
class A {
    int a = 4;
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("Test method of A" );
    }
} 

class B extends A {
    int a = 5;
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("Test method of B" );
    }
    public static void main(String s[]){
        A a= new B();
        System.out.println("Value of a : " a.a );
        System.out.println("Method result " a.test() );
    }
}
```

Output ::

```
Value of a : 4
Mthod result :Test method of B
```

As the B's class test method get called but variable was accessed from super class reference

Comment: `class B extends B` ...what??

Comment: Already explained [here][1] and [here][2]

Regards

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427756/overriding-a-super-class-instance-variables
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983002/how-are-the-variables-overridden-in-java

Answer (score 4):

It's just how java works. When the code has a B but only 'knows' it has an A, the methods of B will be called but the variables of A will get accessed (since there's no 'method overriding equivalent' for variables). I suggest you wrap variables in getters and setters instead of exposing, so you can control their behaviour in subclasses by overriding the getters and setters.

Comment: yes. I want know how java behave in this case

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access variable of Parent class then use
`System.out.println( ((A)a).a );`
Type cast the object to its parent and then access it

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I recommend reading it again.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have a method that accepts a parameter of type A

```
void f(A a) {
     // do something with a.a
}
```

The writer of the `f` method has written this method expecting the behavior that is defined by class A. And you want to change this behavior. When you override a method you may or may not change the behavior, and you should not. You can add some other functionality but never change the expected behavior and if you could override a variable you would definitely change the behavior. Check [Open/Closed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) and [Liskov Substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) [Principles of Object Oriented Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29)